# ruby ignore Relation on index

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I am writing a program to manage my spareparts collection where Spares has_many Spare_parts.

But I need a Index view wich is not like the given

```
 spare_spare_parts GET    /spares/:spare_id/spare_parts(.:format)
```

but independent, like

```
spare_parts GET    /spare_parts(.:format)
```

Here the models

```
class Spare < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :spare_parts
serialize :modells
attr_accessible :preis, :storey, :sn, :anmerkung, :modells, :part, :avatar

has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>" }, :default_url => "/ET/db/images/spare/:style/missing.png"
validates :part, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 2 }
validates :storey, presence: true,
                    length: { minimum: 3 }
def self.search(search)
  if search
    find(:all, :conditions => ['part LIKE ? OR modells LIKE ?',  "%#{search}%", "%#{search}%"])
  else
    find(:all)
  end
end

end
```

and

```
class SparePart < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :spare
  serialize :part
  attr_accessible :part, :storey, :ebay, :spare_id
end
```

I've allready changed my routes.rb to

```
ET::Application.routes.draw do

resources :spares do
resources :spare_parts
end

resources :burners do
resources :burner_items
end
resources :modells
get 'spare_parts' => 'spare_parts#indexall' 

root 'spares#index'
```

and the Spareparts_Controller

```
class SparePartsController < ApplicationController

  def indexall
    @spares = Spare.all
    @spare_parts = @spares.spare_parts.all

  end
```

well,that doesn't work, as well as

```
class SparePartsController < ApplicationController

  def indexall
    @spares = Spare.all
    @spare_parts = Spare_part.all

  end
```

doesn't work neither, but gives me an error

```
Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant Spare_part
```

so how to I get all Spare_parts to my Indexall-view?

```
<h1>Ersatzteile</h1>
<table border="1" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="2" bgcolor="#FFFF00">
    <tr>
    <th>ID </th>
    <th>Beschreibung </th>
    <th>Preis </th>
    <th>Ebay </th>
    <th>Lagerort </th>

    <th colspan="1"></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <% @spares.each do |s| -%>
    <% @spare_parts.each do |p| -%> 
   <tr>
    <td><%= p.id%></td>
    <td><%= p.anmerkung%></td> 
    <td><%= s.preis%></td> 
    <td><%= p.ebay%></td>   
    <td><%= p.storey%></td>

<% end %>  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call `@spare_parts = SparePart.all` in `indexall` (and not `Spare_part.all` as you did).

Comment: Thanx for the help, but this one didn't do it as clean as GabrieleF's tip

Answer (score 0):

In routes.rb, you should repeat the entry for :spare_parts outside of the do...end block of :spares.

```
resources :spares do
  resources :spare_parts
end
resources :spare_parts
```

This will create routes to actions of SparePartsController without the spare parameter.

```
 def index
   @spare_parts = SparePart.joins(:spare)
 end
```

and then you can leave @spares out, and in the view write:

```
...
<td><%= p.spare.preis %></td>
...
```

Comment: Yes, that did it, but I had to change the call in the view,to
       {<% SparePart.all.each do |p| %>}    it works without .all in the other index views            ..............  So THANX A LOT

Comment: Crasy sh... you're right...yesterday it didn't work, now it does... might this error be related to the position of the {def index} in the controller/

Comment: Hi cartasu, glad it helped, Would you mind voting my answer? It was my very first one...

Comment: Yes, I'ld very like to do so, but as it was one of my first questions -->I can't... sorry